# MonoDevelop and Screen Orientation

Tags: monodevelop

I know application questions belong on super user but since this is an IDE I thought I might try it here.

For a couple months now, MonoDevelop likes to appear on my second monitor maximized when I start it up. I have to unmaximize it and move it over each time.

I thought it was some weird preference setting I had messed with but I recently install Windows 7 and the first thing I did was get Monodevelop back up and running. It still goes to that second screen.

Anyone know why?

Comment: MonoDevelop on Windows? Anything wrong with VS Express?

Comment: What's wrong with MonoDevelop?

Comment: I like it and I want to be sure the code I write works in Mono so I might as well write in there first.

Comment: Runtime and IDE aren't that coupled... all is configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a GTK+ Gdk.Screen issue. AFAIK none of the core MD devs have dual-screen setups - and definitely not on all platforms. Best thing to do would be to [file a bug](http://monodevelop.com/Developers#Reporting_Bugs).